# How to fix a "Not ready" error?

Tags: software-installation, wine, playonlinux

I'm trying to install Sims 3 using PlayOnLinux and everything goes really well, until the installer gets to the file `Sims3Launcher.resources.dll` . I then get this response: `Error: Not ready`

I have never seen anything like this before. I tried downloading the .dll file and inserting into the drive myself, but navigating to the directory displayed in the error message resulted in navigating to files on the disc. I obviously can't change those files.

[image]

Is there another library I need to install in PlayOnLinux to make this work?

Thanks,
Tyler